# Why do I see a strange code but only on Firefox?

Tags: wordpress, firefox, google-tag-manager

On a [wordpress installation](https://www.universitaeuropeadiroma.it/), in the header, but only on Firefox, I see a input field with a strange text.

The "strange" HTML code, in the source-code, is just after `<body>` and inside the Google Tag Manager. It is

```
<input><div>lebowski­lebowski</div>
```

And it shows on the page an input field with that funny text.

You can see it here sourrounded by the other strings of HTML.

```
<body class="page-template page-template-templates page-template-temp_ricerca page-template-templatestemp_ricerca-php page page-id-186 wp-custom-logo">
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<input><div>lebowski­lebowski</div>
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-P538SGM" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

I also looked inside the header.php, finding anything of strange

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-P538SGM" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

It could be an injection of code.

Hope you can help me

Comment: i link would help.
lebowski­lebowski  haha. ok, i would download a full backup, files & database. and then search the string with a tool like Textpad 8 Edit->Find in Files
https://www.textpad.com/download/
see if that gets you on track

Comment: Link inserted above. Thanks for your reply

Comment: It is weird. But of course possible. It's definetely injected at some point via js (doesnt mean it's malicious per se), since it's not in the sourcecode itself.  i would still say: first try: download files & database and search "lebowski". maybe it's some debug output... of course, it's very possible that you find nothing. but sometimes these kind of things have the most unexpected source...

Comment: here is your lebowski
https://www.universitaeuropeadiroma.it/wp-content/themes/universita/js/modernizr.js

you can post it here to see it better
https://beautifier.io/

and now we are getting closer
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1052

seems to be a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been a bug in modernizr.js
https://hashnode.com/post/dude-that-carpet-really-tied-the-room-together-cjc225hrm05iz9cwuz18md3mo
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1052

it's fixed in the newer versions. Either update your theme and see if they load a new version or get the js here and replace it in your theme-file. 
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr

Comment: Is it to be updated on client's machine or is the website that has to update it on server side?